# What is the fruit of the lips?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 57:18
I have seen his ways, but I will heal him;
I will lead him and restore comfort to him and his mourners,
19creating the fruit of the lips.
Peace, peace, to the far and to the near,” says the LORD,
“and I will heal him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of Isa 57:18 is disputed.  However, the intent is clear - the fruit of the lips is praise for the LORD.  Note the comments of Ellicott -

> (19) The fruit of the lips . . .—The words point primarily to the
> praise and thanksgiving of the pardoned penitent (comp. Hosea 14:2;
> Hebrews 13:15), but include also all true utterances of the wise of
> heart (Proverbs 10:31). All these alike have their origin in the
> creative fiat of Jehovah, which proclaims “peace” (i.e., salvation) to
> all, whether near or far, Jews in Jerusalem, or Jews in exile, or (as
> in Ephesians 2:17) the Gentiles whose distance was that of spiritual
> remoteness. The message of healing is for all.

Benson is similar -

> Isaiah 57:19-21. I create — I will, by my almighty power, in a
> wonderful manner produce; the fruit of the lips — Praise and
> thanksgiving, termed the fruit of the lips, Hosea 14:2; Hebrews 13:15.
> God creates this fruit of the lips, by giving new subjects and causes
> of thanksgiving, by his mercies conferred on those among his people,
> who acknowledge and bewail their transgressions, and return to him.

Barnes similarly -

> I create the fruit of the lips - The Chaldee and Syriac render this,
> 'The words of the lips.' The 'fruit' of the lips is that which the
> lips produce, that is, words; and the reference here is doubtless to
> offerings of praise and thanksgiving. See Hebrews 13:15; where the
> phrase, 'fruit of the lips' (καρπὸς χειλέων karpos cheileōn), is
> explained to mean praise. Compare Hosea 14:2, where the expression,
> 'we will render the calves of the lips,' means that they would offer
> praise. The sense here is, that God bestowed such blessings as made
> thanksgiving proper, and thus, he 'created the fruit of the lips.'

Comment: You know, the translation of Hosea 14:2 is very bad in most christian translations... The Hebrew literally means that : "we will pay sacrificial bulls with our lips".  The hebrew root of the word ונשלמה is ש.ל.מ means "pay" and very often linked together with sacrifice (pay the sacrifice), for example Psalms 50:14-15...  . Anyway, it is not a good example for the phrase "fruits of lips". Anyway, in the Hebrew meaning there is no OF lips. If you were to translate every word it will be : and we will pay bulls | our lips. The is no connecting word between bulls and lips.